# Unity iOS native share plugin using swift and objective-c

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have a simple *swift* + *objective-c* plugin for my unity project which works. Below is the code for that -

c# -

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using AOT;
using System;
using System.Text;

public class PluginHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI myText;

    public Button shareButton;

    static PluginHelper inst;

    void Awake() {
        inst = this;
    }

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern int shareIOS(int a, int b, Action<string> completionHandler);

    [MonoPInvokeCallback ( typeof ( Action<string> ) )]
    private static void completionHandler ( string s )
    {
        Debug.Log("completed");
        inst.myText.text = "Shared " + s;
    }

    public static void Share() {
        Debug.Log("sharing");
        shareIOS(10, 20, completionHandler);
    }
}
```

objective-c -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "UnityFramework/UnityFramework-Swift.h"

extern "C"
{
    typedef void (*CallbackFunction)();
    typedef void (*CallbackFunctionWithString)( const char * );
    typedef void (*CallbackFunctionWithInt)( NSInteger );
    typedef void (*CallbackFunctionWithFloat)( float );

    // Sometimes I also wanted to send back a 'success' bool, with the string data, so I did that like this:
    typedef void (*CallbackFunctionWithBoolAndString)( bool, const char * );
    // etc ...

    #pragma mark - Functions
    void shareIOS( int a , int b, CallbackFunctionWithString onComplete )
    {
        [[UnityPlugin shared] Share:a:b:onComplete];
    }
}
```

swift code -

```
import Foundation

@objc public class UnityPlugin : NSObject {
    
    public typealias CCallbackFunctionWithString = @convention(c) (UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> Void;
    
    @objc public static let shared = UnityPlugin()
    @objc public func Share(_ a:Int, _ b:Int, _ onComplete:@escaping CCallbackFunctionWithString) -> Void {
        
        onComplete(String(a+b));
    }
}
```

Now I want to add functionality in swift code to let users share content (image, text, link, etc).

I went through [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example) link which suggested using `UIActivityViewController` so I changed my swift code to -

```
import Foundation

@objc public class UnityPlugin : NSObject {
    
    public typealias CCallbackFunctionWithString = @convention(c) (UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> Void;
    
    @objc public static let shared = UnityPlugin()
    @objc public func Share(_ a:Int, _ b:Int, _ onComplete:@escaping CCallbackFunctionWithString) -> Void {
        let items = ["This app is my favorite"]
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        present(ac, animated: true)
        onComplete(String(a+b));
    }
}
```

But this throws compilation error - `Cannot find 'present' in scope`

I tried inheriting it like -

`@objc public class UnityPlugin : NSObject, UIViewController` but found out that swift does not support multiple inheritance.

I found many examples of doing this by objective-c alone but I was wondering if it is possible to do it using swift also. If yes, then how?

Thanks